# How to click on input with submit class if single input is used at multiple places on sam page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following sample of input submit class:

```
<!-- Object name: call-to-action View name: F101_add_to_basket_list --><div class="call-to-action call-to-action-f101">

    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Reservar" name="addToCartButtonSelected"/>

</div><!-- End Object -->
```

I tired

```
document.getElementsByClassName('submit')[0].click();
```

Which is clicking at all places .
I can not change HTML code .

Comment: why not select the element by name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have a class name on the submit button you can do

```
$(".submit").click();
```